# Getting CIImage from UIImage (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Trying to obtain CIImage from UIImage in order to use it for CIFilter, but getting the following exception at the last line:

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,100), false, 0)
let con:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(con)
let im:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let ciimage = CIImage(image: im) // <- Exception here
```

**UPDATE:**
Following the advice not to instantiate CIImage as a variable I reworked my initial code snippet to work in a playground:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,100), false, 0)
let con:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(con)
let im:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//let ciimage = CIImage(image: im) // <- this was causing an exception

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 10, kCIInputImageKey: CIImage(image: im)]) // <- this does not cause an exception
let calayer = CALayer()
calayer.contents = CIContext(options:nil).createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: filter.outputImage.extent())
calayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 270, height: 270)
var view = UIView()
view.frame = calayer.frame
view.layer.addSublayer(calayer)
XCPShowView("view", view)
```

Comment: This fails in a playground but works in compiled code for me - must be a quirk of the playground environment.

Comment: Yeah, works when compiled for me, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are trying to work with filters, I worked around this playground bug:

```
let pic = UIImage(named: "crumpled.jpg")
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
filter.setValue(CIImage(image: pic), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(0.8, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
let ctx = CIContext(options:nil)
let cgImage = ctx.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect:filter.outputImage.extent())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in one line.

UIImage > CIImage

```
let ciimage = CIImage(image: image)
```

CIImage > UIImage

```
let image = UIImage(ciImage: ciimage)
```

Comment: Note that these functions can return nil, and will do so in the most annoying and unexpected of situations. I've yet to find a foolproof way of doing it.